# Detect Content-Type Based on FileName

Tags: java, apache-tika

I'm trying to use Apache Tika to determine the content-type (i.e. - application/pdf for .pdf files). I would like to use Apache Tika's org.apache.tika.detect.NameDetector class. My problem is that it's detect method only accepts an InputStream. I do not have access to the File's InputStream. I only have the File's name (i.e. - myFile.pdf).

Is there any good way to use Apache Tika to determine the content-type based on only the extension/name of the file? (Note - I would like to avoid creating a temp file with the desired name to determine it's content-type.)

Thanks.

Comment: try `org.apache.tika.filetypedetector.TikaFileTypeDetector.probeContentType`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the normal [Apache Tika Detector interface](http://tika.apache.org/1.5/api/org/apache/tika/detect/Detector.html) passing in `null` for the InputStream, and supplying the filename.

Your code would look something like:

```
TikaConfig config = new TikaConfig();

Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, filename);
String mimetype = config.getDetector().detect(null, metadata);
```

To simplify things even more, if you use the [Tika facade class](http://tika.apache.org/1.5/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html) you can just do:

```
Tika tika = new Tika();

String mimetype = tika.detect(filename);
```

And you'll just get back [the mimetype guessed from the filename only](http://tika.apache.org/1.5/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#detect%28java.lang.String%29)

For more information, see the ["Ways of triggering Detection"](http://tika.apache.org/1.5/detection.html#Ways_of_triggering_Detection) documentation on the Apache Tika website.

Answer (score 2):

I did some searching and found a [blog post](https://jeszysblog.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/file-type-detection-with-apache-tika/) which contains a code example that determines the type using the org.apache.tika.Tika class's detect method.

So I could write something like this:

```
org.apache.tika.Tika tika = new org.apache.tika.Tika();
String mimeType = tika.detect("abc.pdf"); // replace abc.pdf with a string variable
```